# How do i make that the new key(keyword) will replace the old key(keyword)?

Tags: c#

In the click button event i did:

```
if (File.Exists(@"d:\Keywords.txt"))
            {
                entries = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\Keywords.txt");
                foreach (string entry in entries)
                {
                    string[] values = entry.Split(',');
                    if (LocalyKeyWords.Count == 0)
                    {
                        LocalyKeyWords[values[0]] = new List<string>();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Clear();
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
                        LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Add(values[i]);
                }
            }
```

The part i added/changed is:

```
if (LocalyKeyWords.Count == 0)
                        {
                            LocalyKeyWords[values[0]] = new List<string>();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Clear();
                        }
```

And when its first time the text file not exist its ok but when the file is exist and already have url's and keys inside im getting the same error on : LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Clear();

The error is: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
And i see that values contain two indexs in index [0] the url and index [1] the key and LocalyKeyWords als contain one index wich is the values.

So how do i solve this problem ?
And how do i load the text file when im running the program in the constructor even if im not clicking the button ?

How do i make that once load the text file when running the program in the constructor and once when clicking the button ?

Thanks.

Comment: I had to add " " around all the ,      since it wont let me post my question since the http format is wrong. so i added "" to all places with , like this "," but in the original code there are no ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read file first and store its values in your dictionary if you do not want to lose all changes. And if you want to overwrite existing keys for urls then you should clear your `List` everytime. For example:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] entries = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Keywords.txt"));
    foreach (string entry in entries)
    {
        string[] values = entry.Split(',');
        LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Clear();
        for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
            LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Add(values[i]); 
    }

    using (var w = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Keywords.txt"))
    {
        crawlLocaly1 = new CrawlLocaly();
        crawlLocaly1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        DialogResult dr = crawlLocaly1.ShowDialog(this);
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl))
            {
                LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Clear(); //probably you could skip this part and create new List everytime
                LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
            }
            else
            {
                LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl] = new List<string>();
                LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in LocalyKeyWords)
            {
                w.WriteLine(kvp.Key + "," + string.Join(",", kvp.Value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JleruOHeP i tried your code after adding some url's and keys the file text file created i closed my program run the program again and clicked the button im getting error. The error is in the foreach where its reading the text file on the line: LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Clear(); the error is: KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary and i checked the text file there are 3 url's and each one have his key. What could be the problem ?

Comment: If it is runned first time, then your Dictionary is empty and you have to create new Lists(). Simplest solution would be to replace LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Clear(); with LocalyKeyWords[values[0]] = new List<string>();

Comment: JleruOHep i tried it not owrking look what i did in the question i updated my question.